# How to make GeoListPlot rectangular?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, geography, geographics

I have a GeoListPlot as below:-

```
gr = {{20, 70}, {-30, 30}};
GeoListPlot[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], GeoRange -> gr]
```

[image]

As you can see, the output is not rectangular. How can I make it rectangular?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe `GeoProjection` helps here?

```
gr = {{20, 70}, {-30, 30}};
GeoListPlot[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
 GeoRange -> gr, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"]
```

[image]

I'd like to include Lucas' comment as I feel it is important:

> Might be worth noting that the default, `GeoProjection->Automatic`, is only non-rectangular (`"LambertAzimuthal"`) at *medium scales* (whatever that is exactly), whereas `"Mercator"` and `"Equirectangular"` (small and large scales, respectively) both appear rectangular. Additionally, any cylindrical projection should do the trick.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the default, `GeoProjection->Automatic`, is only non-rectangular (`"LambertAzimuthal"`) at "medium scales" (whatever that is exactly), whereas `"Mercator"` and `"Equirectangular"` (small and large scales, respectively) both appear rectangular. Additionally, any cylindrical projection should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed. To preserve the projection automatically chosen by GeoGraphics, use the option value GeoRangePadding -> Full, instead of manually setting a cylindrical projection.